# Retrieve all User ID data from Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to use the User ID from Google Analytics for cross-device cohort analysis.

I'm trying to use the GA API to fetch User ID as explained in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference but had no luck so far.

Is there a way to fetch all User IDs stored in GA and then query each and every entity so as to get the details needed?

Comment: I don't think google exposes dimensions via the API that are not visible in the GA interface (which User ID isn't), plus user id is not listed in the dimensions overview (it is usually safe to assume that stuff that is not listed in the documentation just won't work).

Comment: looking for the same thing for hours.. couldn't find any solution yet.. btw, in Google documentation, it says "Although the session data is available via the Core Reporting API, the userId field is not available as a dimension in reports and can not be exported from Analytics." This mention ruined my hours tho :) https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205850?hl=en

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might look into using a [user scoped custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets#example-user).